# winapi SelectObject - DeleteObject - когда нужно удалять обьект

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Вопрос в удалении HGDIOBJ результата возвращаемого функцией `SelectObject(..)`.
Из MSDN документации вообще не очевидно когда надо удалять, там указывается понятие `замещать` - что не во всех случаях очевидно. Например такой код:

```
    HDC hdcMem = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HGDIOBJ hgdi = ::SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmp);
    GetObject(hbmp, sizeof(bitmap), &bitmap);

    ::StretchBlt(..., hdcMem, ...);

    /// ... много всякого всего ...

    ::DeleteObject(hgdi); // <- он тут нужен?
    ::DeleteDC(hdcMem);
```

или

```
    hdcc = ::CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    hobj = ::SelectObject(hdcc, hbmp);

    GetDIBits(hdcc, hbmp, ...);
    SetDIBits(hdcc, hbmp, ...);

    /// ... много всякого всего ...

    ::DeleteObject(hobj);  // <- он тут нужен?
    ::DeleteDC(hdcc);
```

> Эта функция возвращает ранее выбранный объект указанного типа.
>   Приложение должно всегда заменять новый объект оригинальным объектом
>   по умолчанию после завершения рисования новым объектом.

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-selectobject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалять необходимо только те объекты GDI, которые вы сами создали. И удалять их можно только после того, как вы их "отселектили" из GDI контекста. Системные GDI объекты удалять нельзя.

В ваших примерах оба удаления некорректны. Удалять эти объекты нельзя - это системные объекты "по умолчанию", которые находились в контекстах до того, как вы выбрали туда свой объект `hbmp`. Я уверен, что попытки удаления таких системных объектов, не приведут ни к каким негативным последствиям - `DeleteObject` просто ничего не сделает. Но все равно это бессмысленная и некорректная операция.

Вместо удаления вам, как сказано в документации, надо выбрать эти объекты обратно в контекст

```
::SelectObject(hdcMem, hgdi);
::DeleteDC(hdcMem);

// ...
::SelectObject(hdcc, hobj);
::DeleteDC(hdcc);
```

Эти `SelectObject`, возможно, не обязательны, если вы все равно собираетесь следующим же шагом уничтожать эти контексты через `DeleteDC`. Но я бы все-таки их выполнял чисто из соображений аккуратности.

Comment: С первым случаем согласен, а вот второй пример.. там на ровном месте это было создано, обработано и больше оно не понадобиться - тоже удалять нельзя? А куда я его 'выберу' обратно, если этого 'обратно' просто нет?

Comment: @NewView: Не понимаю, о чем вы говорите. В обоих примерах я вижу совершенно одно и то же: попытку удаления "умолочательного" битмапа, полученного из свежесозданного контекста. "Умолчательный" битмап (пустой, скорее всего) - это системный объект, который удалять нельзя.

Comment: В общем понятно, хотя остались интуитивные вопросы на уровне восприятия, спасибо за разъяснения @Ant